# Series of loops

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Been having trouble simplifying this with into a series of loops? Not sure if to do nested / for or while loops. The variable Pnt could potentially be extended to an arbitrarily long number, but variables D and N are always from 1 to 6.

```
Pnt(7,:) = Pnt(1,:) +(-2*D(2)*N(2,:));
Pnt(8,:) = Pnt(1,:) + (-2*D(3)*N(3,:));
Pnt(9,:) = Pnt(1,:) + (-2*D(4)*N(4,:));
Pnt(10,:) = Pnt(1,:) + (-2*D(5)*N(5,:));
Pnt(11,:) = Pnt(1,:) + (-2*D(6)*N(6,:)); 

Pnt(12,:) = Pnt(2,:) + (-2*D(3)*N(3,:));
Pnt(13,:) = Pnt(2,:) + (-2*D(4)*N(4,:));
Pnt(14,:) = Pnt(2,:) + (-2*D(5)*N(5,:));
Pnt(15,:) = Pnt(2,:) + (-2*D(6)*N(6,:));
Pnt(16,:) = Pnt(2,:) + (-2*D(1)*N(1,:));

Pnt(17,:) = Pnt(3,:) + (-2*D(4)*N(4,:));
Pnt(18,:) = Pnt(3,:) + (-2*D(5)*N(5,:));
Pnt(19,:) = Pnt(3,:) + (-2*D(6)*N(6,:));
Pnt(20,:) = Pnt(3,:) + (-2*D(1)*N(1,:));
Pnt(21,:) = Pnt(3,:) + (-2*D(2)*N(2,:));

Pnt(22,:) = Pnt(4,:) + (-2*D(5)*N(5,:));
Pnt(23,:) = Pnt(4,:) + (-2*D(6)*N(6,:));
Pnt(24,:) = Pnt(4,:) + (-2*D(1)*N(1,:));
Pnt(25,:) = Pnt(4,:) + (-2*D(2)*N(2,:));
Pnt(26,:) = Pnt(4,:) + (-2*D(3)*N(3,:));

Pnt(27,:) = Pnt(5,:) + (-2*D(6)*N(6,:));
Pnt(28,:) = Pnt(5,:) + (-2*D(1)*N(1,:));
Pnt(29,:) = Pnt(5,:) + (-2*D(2)*N(2,:));
Pnt(30,:) = Pnt(5,:) + (-2*D(3)*N(3,:));
Pnt(31,:) = Pnt(5,:) + (-2*D(4)*N(4,:));

Pnt(32,:) = Pnt(6,:)  + (-2*D(1)*N(1,:));
Pnt(33,:) = Pnt(6,:)  + (-2*D(2)*N(2,:));
Pnt(34,:) = Pnt(6,:)  + (-2*D(3)*N(3,:));
Pnt(35,:) = Pnt(6,:)  + (-2*D(4)*N(4,:));
Pnt(36,:) = Pnt(6,:)  + (-2*D(5)*N(5,:));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using 2 loops:

```
% Don't forget to pre-allocate memory for Pnt
p=7;  q=1;  r=1;  %Initializing the variables to be used in the loop
while p<=36       % Since last row of Pnt to be calculated is 36th
    for s=1:5     % Since each row of Pnt is used 5 times
        r = mod(r,6); %Since maximum value for rows of D and N is 6
        Pnt(p,:) = Pnt(q,:) + (-2*D(r+1)*N(r+1,:));  %Expression
        p=p+1;  r=r+1;
    end
    q=q+1;  r=q;
end
```

Comment: Absolute legend. Thank you so much @Sardar_Usama

Comment: This is the more traditional loop implementation I was looking for. For some reason when I initialised Pnt = zeros(36,3) it filled it with wrong values @Sardar_Usama

Comment: @ThomasShemeld It seems that you initialised `Pnt` after the calculation of `Pnt(1,:)` to `Pnt(6,:)` and just before the code in my answer. If that's the case, initialise `Pnt=zeros(36,3)` before calculating or inputting `Pnt(1,:)` to `Pnt(6,:)`

Answer (score 0):

[`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) provides a handy way of performing element-wise operation on two arrays with implicit size-extension. The following is a way of implementing what you want in a more compact fashion using this funciton.

```
% compute the product of D and N beforehand for efficiency
DN = -2 * bsxfun(@times, N, (D(:)));

% compute new points in for-loop. 5 new points are generated
%    in each iteration. Run longer for more points.
for ii=1:6
    Pnt(1+ii*5+(1:5), :) = bsxfun(@plus, DN(mod(ii+(0:4), 6)+1, :), Pnt(mod(ii-1, 6)+1, :));
end
```

Comment: Would this implementation be faster if I happened to be calculating c. >10000 points? @aksadv

Comment: I would think so. Would be nice if you timed both methods and let us know.